# default object in N1QL results

Tags: couchbase, sql++

When I query Couchbase using N1QL I always get the results under an object named 'default'. I searched through the documentation but couldn't find anything mentioning this object. Also none of the examples in the documentation show this object in the query results. Where does it come from and how can I get rid of it? Is it something to do with the 'default' bucket?

Sample query result:

```
"default": {
    "$type": "MetaPage, Core",
    "Datasources": [
        {
            "Data": null,
            "EntityTypeName": "book",
            "Name": "book_data",
            "Query": "SELECT * FROM `default` WHERE Id = 'lotr' AND Type = 'entity_type';"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is the **default** bucket in your query.

A couple of solutions.

```
SELECT default.* ...

SELECT RAW default FROM default ...
```